# Adding labels to list based on model properties

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

I have an ember application which displays a list of users. I would like to add a label to each item in the list to indicate if a user is available or offline, something like the logic in this pseudocode:

```
if (user.state == "available")
//add a green label 
else if (user.state == "idle")
//add an orange label
else 
//add a red label
```

Is this possible to do from within the template or does it need to go in a separate JavaScript function? I'm very new to web development and ember. Here's my html with my attempt at adding a green bootstrap label:

```
<script type = "text/x-handlebars" id = "users">

<div class="col-md-2">
{{#link-to "users.create"}}<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></button> {{/link-to}}
</div>
<div class="col-md-10">

  <ul class="list-group">
  {{#each user in controller}}

  <li class="list-group-item">
//Add a green label if user is online

if (user.state == "online")
{
    {{#link-to "user" user}}
      {{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}
    {{/link-to}}
<span class="label label-success">Online</span>
}
  </li>
{{/each}}

</ul>

{{outlet}}
</div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a computed property called `isOnline` like this:

```
isOnline: function() {
  return this.get('state') == 'online';
}.property('state')
```

And in your template check using:

```
{{#if user.isOnline}}                    
  <span class="label label-success">Online</span>
{{else}}
  <span class="label label-danger">Offline</span>
{{/if}}
```

Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/NSuS3/

Comment: That looks good, but I want to do it with bootstrap labels as opposed to changing the entire background color?

Comment: My apologies I was going in the wrong way. I updated the answer, please give a look.

Comment: Hmmm, this is very close to what I need but is showing all users as being offline, even though I know that the state of some of them is definitely online?

Comment: I included the isOnline function in my userController.js file, and added Console.log('fired'); to it. Nothing happens when I load the page- the 'fired message does not appear. Is there somewhere else I should put the function?

Comment: I don't know why you have these problems, but to use computed properties you need to use some Ember.Object subclass, plain js objects won't work. And if you want to put the computed property in the controller, you will need to use an itemController, [these docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html) explain how to do that.

Comment: My userController extends ObjectController!